# How to use image_url from dataset in Carto Builder HOVER pop-up window?

Tags: carto, html, html-popup

I am creating a map in Carto Builder with several points. I want to set the pop-up (hover) to display information from my dataset, including an image which is dictated by the corresponding image_url column in my dataset.

Below is the new HTML for the hover popup window. How do I get the image to actually appear? No matter what I do or what small syntax changes I make I just cannot get the image to show up!

```
<div class="CDB-Tooltip CDB-Tooltip--isLight">
  <ul class="CDB-Tooltip-list">
   <li class="CDB-Tooltip-listItem">
      <img style="width:100px;height:auto" src="{{image_url}}">>
   <li class="CDB-Tooltip-listItem">
      <h3 class="CDB-Tooltip-listTitle">name</h3>
      <h4 class="CDB-Tooltip-listText">{{name}}</h4>
   </li>
   <li class="CDB-Tooltip-listItem">
     <h3 class="CDB-Tooltip-listTitle">university</h3>
     <h4 class="CDB-Tooltip-listText">{{university}}</h4>
   </li>
   <li class="CDB-Tooltip-listItem">
     <h3 class="CDB-Tooltip-listTitle">class_year</h3>
     <h4 class="CDB-Tooltip-listText">{{class_year}}</h4>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: "hover" popup window HTML and actual window on map - the image is not appearing.]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please have a read of the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for new users. In addition to your screenshot, could you please add the code you're using as a codeblock?  And explain what you have tried?

Comment: Added the code as a codeblock! And I have tried several different small syntax changes: spacing, quotations, using height and width tags instead of a style tag, etc.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `{{image_url}}` as a header to see what text (if any) is displayed? This may help with troubleshooting to make sure the urls are correctly formatted. Additionally, this may require some custom javascript

Answer (score 3):

First I would check that your image_url field is a string and that the urls are valid and working.

It looks like your html for inserting an image doesn't have the proper syntax, you can specify the width/height in-line or preferably in your css.

Try:

```
<img src="{{image_url}}" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

Carto also has documentation on [Enabling Pop-Up information](https://carto.com/learn/guides/publish-share/enabling-pop-up-information-windows)
**Edit:** for pop-up on hover, there are a few examples that illustrate this using cartojs you could adapt these examples for your use case. Here's a sleek example from carto for [Hobbit Filming locations](http://cartodb.github.io/cartodb.js/examples/TheHobbitLocations/) and another that changes the [outline of a feature on hover](http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/8313604).  Looks likes `vis.overlay` is the syntax to replace for on hover rather than on click from their [cartojs faq](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/infowindows#creating-an-infowindow-with-the-createvis-function).

Example from their docs:

```
layer.leafletMap.viz.addOverlay({
  type: 'tooltip',
  layer: sublayer,
  template: '<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content-wrapper"><img style="width: 100%" src={{_url}}>{{name}}, {{age}}, {{city}}, {{country}}</div>', 
  position: 'bottom|right',
  fields: [{ name: 'name' }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried your syntax and it is still not appearing. additionally, the guide you linked references "pop ups with images" and the only option given is to use the "image" preset selection for a "click" window (I need an image in my "hover" pop up, not "click").

Comment: Whoops! I added info for on hover, looks like custom javascript may be your best bet if you can't figure it out in their builder.